# Displaying picture collections from a user's picture library

Tags: c#, performance, xaml, uwp

Currently, I have been digging up my old codes. One of the applications I worked on was an Image editing phone app that displays a collection of random pictures from a user's picture, which I limited to less than 80 pictures because of performance. These random pictures are chosen from different folders in the pictures Library and read as a bitmapImage to give the user a general flip view of their pictures.

Although, I have initialised the pictures to display in the constructor of my ViewModel which is bad because it takes a bit of time( almost 1 min) to load up the data. I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged because I allow the user to create an album of pictures from the display or subset and save it as a gif image but I will not be reviewing that at the moment

```
public class PictureVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   public PictureVM()
    {
        Task.Run(() => loadData());   
    }
ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> pictures = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();

private ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> _pictureGallery;
public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> PictureGallery
{
    get { return _pictureGallery; }
    set
    {
        if (_pictureGallery != value)
        {
            _pictureGallery = value;
            onPropertyChanged("PictureGallery");
        }
    }
}



public async void loadData()
    {
       StorageFolder recentPictures = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
       IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> recentImagesInLibrary = await recentPictures.GetFilesAsync();
       IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> subfolders = await recentPictures.GetFoldersAsync();
       IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> subfolderImages;
       await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                     {
                         // tranversing the pictures library current folder
                         foreach (var item in recentImagesInLibrary)
                         {
                             BitmapImage BitImage = new BitmapImage();
                             var stream = await item.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                             BitImage.SetSource(stream);
                             pictures.Add(BitImage);
                         }

                         foreach (var subfolderItem in subfolders)
                         {
                             subfolderImages = await subfolderItem.GetFilesAsync();
                             foreach (var subfolderItemImages in subfolderImages)
                             {
                                 BitmapImage BitImage2 = new BitmapImage();
                                 var stream2 = await subfolderItemImages.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                                 BitImage2.SetSource(stream2);

                                 if (pictures.Count < 80)
                                 {
                                     pictures.Add(BitImage2);
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     break;
                                 }

                             }

                         }
                         PictureGallery = pictures;
                     } ); 
  }}
```

The flipview in xaml looks like this at the moment

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView" Height="500" ItemsSource="{Binding PictureGallery}" Visibility="Visible"  Margin="0,0">
                            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Height="680"  Width="680"  Source="{Binding}"   />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                        </FlipView>
```

How can I improve the way the data is loaded (performance wise)? Is there a way to load more images without performance trade off? How do I improve my randomised image selection from the user's library? Any suggestions will be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which I limited to less than 80 pictures because of performance

This is not correct. If in the `recentImagesInLibrary` are e.g 200 pictures you are loading all of them. The limiting is only happening in the second loop (the inner one).

---

- A thing which bothers me as well is that you are requesting the `subfolders` although you might not need them.
- By extracting the picture loading to a separate method you can get rid of some duplicated code.
- you aren't consistent with using `var`. E.g I would expect using `var` here: `BitmapImage BitImage2 = new BitmapImage();`.
- local variables should be named using `camelCase` casing, so e.g `BitImage2` => `bitImage2`
- methods should be named `PascalCase` casing. Please take a look at the [C# naming guideline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx)
- `async` methods should be named `xxxAsync` see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14652922/2655508
- by having the `pictures.Count < 80` condition only in the inner loop you are doing more work than is needed. For each `subFolderItem` you are loading at least one image although the condition might be reached already.
- the stream you are opening for each image should be properly disposed/closed after it isn't needed anymore. This can be done by enclosing it inside of a `using` statement.
- `80` is a magic number. By using a meaningful named variable/const you would always know what it is about. You should consider to pass it as a constructor ment so you could control it from the outside of the class.
- if you are using C# 6 (VS 2015)  you could use the [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) operator.
  Instead of `onPropertyChanged("PictureGallery");` you would then write `onPropertyChanged(nameof(PictureGallery));` which is a little bit longer, but if you later on decide to rename the property you wouldn't need to worry about changeing the string `"PictureGallery"` as well.

  ---

**Disclaimer:** I usually don't use `async`, so if anything is wrong...

Implementing the mentioned points leads to

```
private const int MaximumPicturesToLoad = 80;
private int maximumPicturesToLoad;

public PictureVM() : this(MaximumPicturesToLoad)
{}

public PictureVM(int maximumPicturesToLoad)
{
    this.maximumPicturesToLoad = maximumPicturesToLoad;
    Task.Run(() => loadData());   
}

private async void LoadImagesAsync(StorageFolder folder)
{
    if (AreMaximumPicturesLoaded())
    {
        return;
    }

    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> imageFiles = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (var file in imageFiles)
    {
        pictures.Add(await LoadImageAsync(file));
        if (AreMaximumPicturesLoaded())
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> subFolders = await folder.GetFoldersAsync();
    foreach (var subFolder in subFolders)
    {
        LoadImagesAsync(subFolder);
    }
}
private async Task<BitmapImage> LoadImageAsync(StorageFile file)
{
    var image = new BitmapImage();

    using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        image.SetSource(stream);
    }

    return image;
}
private bool AreMaximumPicturesLoaded()
{
    pictures.Count == maximumPicturesToLoad
}
```

Comment: `maximumPicturesToLoad` should be a `const`ant and renamed to use PascalCase.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 fixed answer